# Ajax or jquery call for this request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i need your help to call this script with jquery or ajax?

```
                                    <div id="mydiv">
                                     <div class="ccbillWidgetContainer">
                                        <script type="text/javascript" class="CCBillWidget1232a86c-1234-1234-1234-41d1aafa7e75_12332" src="https://images.ccbill.com/flexforms2/ccbill-widget-live.js">
                                            {
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "clientSubacc": "0002",
                                                    "initialPrice": "10.00",
                                                    "initialPeriod": "0",
                                                    "currencyCode": "124",
                                                    "formDigest":  "1234545765635445234"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        </script>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
```

i have made this. but the script its not generated

```
$("#mydiv").append('<div class="ccbillWidgetContainer"><script id="testccbill" type="text/javascript" class="CCBillWidget1232a86c-1234-1234-1234-41d1aafa7e75_12332" src="https://images.ccbill.com/flexforms2/ccbill-widget-live.js">' +
                            '{' +
                            '"parameters": {' +
                            '"clientSubacc": "0002",' +
                            '"initialPrice": "3.00",' +
                            '"initialPeriod": "0",' +
                            '"currencyCode": "124",' +
                            '"formDigest": "1234545765635445234"' +
                            '}' +
                            '}' +
                            '<\/script></div>');
```

Comment: That is not how you append `script` tags, nor is it how you would inject JS content in to a page. Can you please describe your goal. Right now this is an X/Y question about your proposed solution, which is not workable.

Comment: This script is called by csv or xml to generate a payment button widget that comes from a third party platform.

like this
<div class="ccbillWidgetContainer"><script type="text/javascript" class="CCBillWidget123457bb-4567-4e7d-4567-3b829eb6f000_18248" src="https://images.ccbill.com/flexforms2/ccbill-widget-live.js"></script></div>

to change prices dynamically, you need to push parameters